# oasis picks up wrong ocamlbuild

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocamlfind, oasis

I try to compile an Ocaml project with an Ocaml version provided by Opam.
My ocamlbuild, ocamlfind, and oasis seem OK :

```
/Users/fred/.opam/4.02.1/bin/ocamlbuild
dhcp-182-73:compil fred$ which ocamlfind
/Users/fred/.opam/4.02.1/bin/ocamlfind
dhcp-182-73:compil fred$ which oasis
/Users/fred/.opam/4.02.1/bin/oasis
```

But when I try to compile, it seems that a wrong version of ocamlbuild is called, and even the version of ocamlfind is right, I think that it explains why ocamlfind can't find the sexplib library.

```
$ make
ocaml setup.ml -build 
Finished, 0 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
+ /Users/fred/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind ocamldep -package threads -package sexplib.syntax -package core -package comparelib.syntax -modules  src/tricot/tricot.mli > src/tricot/tricot.mli.depends
ocamlfind: Package `sexplib.syntax' not found
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 1 target (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
E: Failure("Command ''/usr/local/bin/ocamlbuild' src/tricot/tricot.cma src/tricot/tricot.cmxa src/tricot/tricot.a src/tricot/tricot.cmxs src/compil/compil.cma src/compil/compil.cmxa src/compil/compil.a src/compil/compil.cmxs src/main.native -use-ocamlfind -tag debug' terminated with error code 10")
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

I've tried to tell oasis which version of ocambuild to use without success, does someone knows how it could be done ?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try deleting `setup.data` and running `make` again. Oasis caches the paths the first time you try to build, and doesn't update them automatically afterwards. Perhaps you tried to build it, then used `opam switch`, then tried to build it again?

Comment: Thanks, it works! when I tried 'make' after that, my path for ocamlbuild and ocamlfind where pointing to my Opam repo. I think I've upgraded my version of OCaml since last time I built my project

Answer (score 3):

You must be missing a

```
eval $(opam config env)
```

See the documentation of [`opam switch`](http://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Usage.html#opamswitch).

Note that normally `opam`'s install procedure should have made so that this gets invoked automatically on new shells. You may want to run `opam init` again it will prompt you to agree to make changes to your `.profile` so that everything is in order when you start new shells.

EDIT: In fact it looks like you changed to the `system` switch between the two invocations you show us. So it seems that in the `system` switch `sexp` is not installed. In anycase whenever you `opam switch` in a shell always invoke the command I mentioned above so that the right paths are setup.

Comment: Thanks, actually it do not see any shift..
Opam points out the 4.02.1 version, and I didn't try to change it.

Comment: When I check my library with Ocamlfind, it is OK : ocamlfind query sexplib
/Users/fred/.opam/4.02.1/lib/sexplib
And when I check with opam list, sexplib is displayed.

Comment: So I think that the problem comes from oasis. I've looked in my setup.data file, it is written        
ocamlc="/usr/local/bin/ocamlc.opt"            
ocamlopt="/usr/local/bin/ocamlopt.opt"              
ocamlbuild="/usr/local/bin/ocamlbuild"              
But I don't understand why it doesn't choose my version of these programs which are in /Users/fred/.opam/4.02.1/bin/   ??

Comment: Well I don't know what's behind this `make`

Comment: You can find my _oasis file on [github](https://github.com/TriComp/TriComp/blob/master/compil/_oasis), but I can build my project now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Thomas's answer, you can discard the configuration by

```
ocaml setup.ml -distclean
```